# Generate an array of persons with parameters introduced by the user

Tags: java

In my schoolwork assignment, I am asked to build a system where I'll have a menu with a bunch of functionalities, but the main point is that it is about scheduling doctor and nurse appointments. To start off, I thought, as we may have a lot of different people (normal people who are sick and want to schedule an appointment, doctors and nurses), I should create a "Person" class, and be able to create a bunch of people with a set of parameters. On my way to it, I find myself with an error that says that my array is null, even though the user is supposed to insert the information.

Here's what I have in my Menu class so far. The part I'm trying to accomplish right now is just the number 1 on the menu, which means add a person, which I want to store in memory afterwards, and program the option 2 which is show people that are stored in memory.

```
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Menu {
    Person people[] = new Person[9];
     public Menu(){

     }
    void showMenu(){
        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option;
        System.out.println("==== Managing medical appointments ====");
        System.out.println("1 - Add a person");
        System.out.println("2 - Show people");
        System.out.println("2 - Book an appointment");
        System.out.println("3 - De-select an appointment");
        System.out.println("4 - Show all appointments");
        System.out.println("5 - Show appointments by date");
        System.out.println("6 - Average enquiry time");
        System.out.println("7 - Average time of enquiries by date");
        System.out.println("8 - Save queries");
        System.out.println("9 - Read queries");
        System.out.println("0 - Exit");
        System.out.println("Choose the desired option: ");
        option = r.nextInt();
        switch(option){
            case 1: addPerson();
                break;
            case 2: showPeople();
                break;
        }
    }
    public void showPeople(){
         for (int i =0 ; i< people.length ; i++){
             System.out.println(people[i]);
         }
    }
    public void addPerson() {
        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nId;
        String name = "nothing";
        int nTel;
        System.out.println("Enter ID number: ");
        nId = r.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the person's name: ");
        name = r.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter phone number: ");
        nTel = r.nextInt();
        people[0].setPerson(nId,name,nTel);

    }
}
```

And here's what is on my main. I have a whole lot of other classes, like establishment, which will extend to Hospital or Health center, Appointment, and so on. In this case on main, all I've done is create a Menu type of object, and call the showMenu function I've made.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        menu.showMenu();
    }

}
```

The error I get when I run my main:

```
==== Medical appointment management ====
1 - Add a person
2 - Show people
2 - Book an appointment
3 - Cancel an appointment
4 - Show all appointments
5 - Show appointments by date
6 - Average appointment time
7 - Average appointment time by date
8 - Save appointments 
9 - Read appointments
0 - Exit
Choose the desired option: 
1
Enter the identification number: 
12313123
Enter the person's name: 
Enter the phone number: 
9712312
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Person.setPerson(int, String, int)" because "this.persons[0]" is null
    at Menu.addPerson(Menu.java:49)
    at Menu.showMenu(Menu.java:27)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

As you can see, it shows the menu, I go for option 1, which is add person, and then he starts asking for the parameters I've included in the class, but first off, for some reason it just skips the name right off, and then he gives me that error, telling me that my array is null.

EDITED : translated the program as suggested, hopefully it's easier. Thanks!

Comment: Translating the program should make it way easier to understand ;)

Comment: You need to create a new instance of `Pessoa` and put it in the appropriate location *(index)*. You have an array of a size, but it's empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused because you are not creating a new instance of `Pessoa`. So in order to fix this use the following code

```
people[0] = new Person(); //Make sure to pass parameters if they exist
people[0].setPerson(nId,name,nTel);
```

**Avoid using arrays for a program like this** instead consider use [ArrayList](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nRj4ALuw7A&pp=ygUKamF2YSBsaXN0cw%3D%3D)s

Comment: Thank you. About the ArrayLists. In this project, teacher said we could only use ArrayLists if it was for removing, adding or consulting something on a list. And by the way, do you have any idea, why is the program ignoring the name ?? It just goes onto the nextline without letting the user introduce it.

Comment: @JoséFilipeSilva sorry but I am unable to understand your question, could you please explain (also accept the answer if it works)

Comment: When I run the program, and I choose the option 1 from the menu, it will ask the user to introduce 3 parameters about himself, but for some reason, after I insert the 1st one, it skips the 2nd which is the name, and goes straight to the 3rd.

Comment: Maybe check this ->https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/21252090

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read/write an empty array field. However, this field does not yet exist at the current time. To do this, you must first save an object in this field. This can be done in the following way.

```
people[id] = new Person();
perople[id].setPerson(nId, name, nTel)
```

At this point, I recommend creating a constructor for the Person object, which takes the values for nId, name, nTel directly and sets them for the object.
In addition, such usecases are actually more likely to be implemented in an ArrayList, as this is dynamically expandable and does not have a fixed size.

An example:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>

//now you can just add a new Person like this
Person newPerson = new Person();
newPerson.setPerson(nId, name, nTel);
perople.add(newPerson);

//and you can read a Person by its Index in the List. (kinda like in a Array)
```